# how to set the correct path for file download in zendframework2

Tags: zend-framework2, download

my controller:

```
public function downloadAction()
    {
        $param['filename'] = $this->params()->fromRoute('filename');
$param['foldername'] = $this->params()->fromRoute('foldername');
    $fileName = $param['filename']; //bala.pdf
    $folderName = $param['foldername'];  //j1005

$fileContents = file_get_contents($fileName);

$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setContent($fileContents);

$headers = $response->getHeaders();
$headers->clearHeaders()
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' .$fileName . '"')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', strlen($fileContents));


return $this->response;
}
```

my file location is ./data/basepaper/j1005/bala.pdf , but i dont know how to set the path for download the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be good for you to assign your variable properly (initialise empty array for instance before use) and to use your variables (the array is only used to assign the variables again...).

Concerning the current problem, you need to understand the basic of the file management on ZF2, and therefore read the index.php:

```
<?php
    /**
     * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
     * to the application root now.
     */
    chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

Which means you can refer to any file from the root directory of your project.

So your code become:

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    // Combine assignation (unused array, and non initialised...)
    $fileName = $this->params()->fromRoute('filename');
    $folderName = $this->params()->fromRoute('foldername');

    $fileContents = file_get_contents("data/basepaper/{$folderName}/{$fileName}");

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setContent($fileContents);

    $headers = $response->getHeaders();
    $headers->clearHeaders()
            ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
            ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' .$fileName . '"')
            ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', strlen($fileContents));

    return $this->response;
}
```